# Exception while sockets reading

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, windows-services

I'm doing SMS sending application using Sockets. I'm getting this expection:

> An unhandled exception of type `'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'` occurred in `System.dll`

[image: Screen shot of code and exception]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format blockquotes and the image so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Can you post the hole code, specially the ReceiveCallback code